# find specific item from DataTable or XML

Tags: .net, xml, csv, datatable, c++-cli

Hi I'm havin the problem thet I need to get an text from an DataTable.
I read an csv-file to the datatable and wondering now how can I access an specific row
Ma Datatable contains the translations for various texts and has Columns for the different languages
e.g.

English, German, Italian, French,...

What I need to get is the translation for an english text.

I tried the following with no result:

(The csv file has some duplicates so I remove them.)

```
printf("reading csv file...\n");
DataTable^ table = GetDataTable( L"LangTexts.csv", '|' );
DataSet^ data = gcnew DataSet("LANGS");
printf("removing duplicate rows...\n");
RemoveDuplicateRows( table, L"English" );
table->TableName = "LanguageText";
table->Namespace = "Nmspce";
printf("saving as XML\n");
data->WriteXml( "LangTexte.xml" );

table->PrimaryKey = gcnew array<DataColumn^> {table->Columns["English"]};
```

// does not work it says the columns are not unique (Zusätzliche Informationen: Diese Spalten haben momentan keine eindeutigen Werte.)

After that I have an xml file which looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Nmspce>
  <LanguageText xmlns="Nmspce">
    <English>Back</English>
    <Deutsch>Zurück</Deutsch>
    <Français>Retour</Français>
    <Svenska>Tillbaka</Svenska>
    <Português>voltar</Português>
    <Español>Volver</Español>
    <Slovensko>Nazaj</Slovensko>
    <Polski>Powrot</Polski>
    <Suomi>Takaisin</Suomi>
    <Nederlands />
    <Česky>Zpět</Česky>
    <Italiano>Indietro</Italiano>
    <Română>Înapoi</Română>
  </LanguageText>
....
```

How can I now get e.g. german text for a specific enlisch text?

I tried this with no luck:

This does not work, "from" is not known by compiler:

```
String ^strToGet = "Torque";
    String^ sDeutsch = ( From DataRow dr in table->Rows where safe_cast<String^>( table["English"] ) 
                          == strToGet select ( String^ )table["German"] )->FirstOrDefault();
```

This does not work, the filteredrows array is empty:

```
array<DataRow^>^ filteredRows = table->Select( String::Format( "'{0}' like '%{1}%'", "English", strToGet) );
     String^ res;
     if(filteredRows != nullptr && filteredRows->Length > 0)
       res = cli::safe_cast<String^>(filteredRows[0]["Deutsch"]);
     else
       res= strToGet;
```

This complains that the table has no primary key:

```
DataRow^ r = table->Rows->Find(strToGet);
if(r != nullptr)
{
   String^ sDe = cli::safe_cast<String^>(r["Deutsch"]);
}
```

What ca I do to solve the problem?
Or do you have an better way to deal with the translation list from an csv-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after long time I was remembering my own question here. Just to give feedback to anyone who stumbls upon this case.

It all ended up with this:

The **only** thing which works is to have a List which has **absolutely NO DUPLICATES**. 
So the code above works, but the source-csv-file must not have duplicate entries for the desired "primary key"-column. 
**Removing duplicate entries afterwards** with "RemoveDuplicateRows( table, L"English" );" **has no effect**. the index is broken before.

I wrote a different tool (exe) with that I remove the duplicate rows from the csv-file before I import it here to this code. 
After doing so, all is file.